# Online College Class Grades

Tags: grades

My professor for my online class refuses to grade two late assignments because they were too late to grade. They were only two days late, and she has graded one that was later than that, but she won't grade these ones. Those two assignments tanked my grade to failing. I am freaking out, it is a college class that I don't have enough money to pay to retake it. What can I do to change her mind?

Comment: Probably not much,especially if this is the third time you hand in late. Deadlines are there for a reason.

Comment: I do not think anyone can answer.  However, it is possible that the online learning system does not allow your professor to input a grade for those assignments.  In that case, your task would be (1) to motivate your professor to change that; and (2) to grade the assignment.

Comment: She graded one by *another student* that was even later than you, or an earlier one that *you* handed in when it was due for four days already?

Comment: @MorganRodgers That sounds an awful lot like an Answer.

Answer (score 7):

If the policy is that late assignments aren't accepted, then late is late. Just because you got a pass once, doesn't guarantee another pass (let alone two more). Next time, get your assignments in on time, especially if you are paying a lot of money to take the course.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you hand in late assignments, you are at the mercy of the instructor.  Certainly where I work there is no guarantee the instructor will mark these copies at all or without penalties.

It could very well be that your instructor graciously allowed you to submit a late assignment once, but that was it.  I can easily see that an instructor would not want students to habitually submit assignments late, quite frankly a hard line on this is not unwarranted.

Comment: I interpret the OP as saying the instructor graded another student's assignment who was even later, which is conceivable if there were mitigating circumstances.

Comment: @Allure you could be right but no third party is mentioned by OP.  Either way it’s imprudent to count on anything once due date is passed.